# which visa should i opt for (attending a conference in UK)

Tags: visas, uk

I am attending a conference in school of mathematics, Edinburgh.

[image]

I am looking for option of standard visitor visa but I could not find in the options.

[image]

Should I opt for short-term student visa?

I will be in UK for period of 15 days.

Comment: Are you sure the standard visitor visa isn't listed under either *S* or *V?*  It's not possible to say from that image.  A short-term student visa is almost certainly incorrect, since you will not be enrolling in a course of study.

Comment: there is an option of "Visit"... Could that be another name for "standard visitor visa"? @phoog

Comment: Yes, "visit" would be the same as "standard visitor."

Comment: It's a bit odd that it is written in all capital letters, however.

Comment: do you know if I can change the visa type in the application form? I clicked as short-term student visa now I have to change it to visit visa.. @phoog can you please help me

Comment: @phoog, on the other hand there's also both "Tier 5" and "TIER 5", so I think it's just a matter of crappy quality control of their IT...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A student visa is definitely the wrong choice, since you will not be enrolling as a student.  As noted in the comments, the list includes "Visit," which is the item you should select.

Comment: https://myappointment.vfsglobal.co.uk this is the site I have logged in to